# What is the difference between CHECKSUM_AGG() and CHECKSUM()?

Tags: t-sql

What is the difference between CHECKSUM_AGG() and CHECKSUM() ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- [`CHECKSUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) calculates a hash for *one or more values in a single row* and returns an integer.
- [`CHECKSUM_AGG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188920.aspx) is an aggregate function that takes *a single integer value from multiple rows* and calculates an aggregated checksum for each group.

They can be used together to checksum multiple columns in a group:

```
SELECT category, CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(*)) AS checksum_for_category
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 5):

CHECKSUM_AGG will perform a checksum across all the values that are being aggregated, coming up with a value.
It's typically used to see if a collection of values (in the group) has generally changed.

CHECKSUM is intended to build a hash index based on an expression or column list.
One example of using a CHECKSUM is to store the unique value for the entire row in a column for later comparison.